# Tensorflow custom loss showing incorrect verbose

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using `1 - dice_coefficient` as a loss metric, i am getting absurd loss in the following verbose while training using tensorflow 2.0, currently i introduced activity regularisers in every conv2d layer (l2 regularisation).

Loss is being calculated correctly why is the verbose incorrect?

```
Epoch 1/10

 loss:  0.6226288  dice:  0.37737122
    1/32057 [..............................] - ETA: 164:21:12 - loss: 58262.4844 - dice_coef: 0.3774
 loss:  0.66217625  dice:  0.33782378
    2/32057 [..............................] - ETA: 92:42:14 - loss: 47621.1680 - dice_coef: 0.3576 
 loss:  0.7298874  dice:  0.27011257
    3/32057 [..............................] - ETA: 68:58:37 - loss: 41726.3203 - dice_coef: 0.3284
 loss:  0.91065186  dice:  0.089348145
    4/32057 [..............................] - ETA: 57:40:56 - loss: 36527.0034 - dice_coef: 0.2687
 loss:  0.6360147  dice:  0.36398527
```

Comment: What's the value for the regularizer coefficients, and how many trainable parameters does your model have?

Comment: Hi @Sagar Sarkale, can you give a minimum reproducible code and a bit of explanation of your argument?